# JQuery ajax not sending request

Tags: jquery

Newbie question please bear with me. Here is a simple ajax code: click button to delete an image on server. But in Firebug>Net>XHR, I cannot see this request.

PS: I set the delete button's type to "button" rather than "submit" to prevent page refresh, is that correct practice?

```
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
    var path = currentpath + '/delete';
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    var data = {};
    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrftoken;
    data ['filename'] = $('.image-input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('button.delete').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

**EDIT: code for delete button**

```
<button type='button' class='delete first'>&#x274C</button>
```

**EDIT2: intention of the code**

All I need is to pass a filename string to server, so server can query image by that string and delete that image. And I don't want the page to refresh.

Comment: can u show delete button code

Comment: Have you tried setting the `dataType: 'json'`?

Comment: show the code for delete

Comment: are you getting any errors on the console window?

Comment: @Jude, absolutely no error shown in Firebug console. Only problems is the xhr request is not made

Comment: try the chrome console maybe?

Comment: @PSR, I put alert inside and it shows up when clicked. So the selector is valid.

Answer (score 2):

Access your button class click like below:

```
$(document).on("click", ".delete", function(){
    // YOUR CODE STUFF
});
```

For details please have a look at [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

Comment: I read the doc but don't get it. All my code is already wrapped in `$(document).ready`. Why need to `$(document).on`? Maybe I just don't get the syntax. Could you comment your code here?

Comment: If you have already wrapped code in the `$(document).ready` then you can use parent element that holds `button` element.

`$('#WRAPPER').on("click", ".delete", function(){ // CODE STUFF HERE })`
The doc will help. If you cant get help, please comment.

Comment: As I understand, at least the sytax of the jquery selector is valid. I put alert inside on function and it gets called. So I think problem is the ajax part. Not sure how your answer will affect the ajax part.

Comment: If you are having problem in the ajax part, give a try tp Parv Sharma's answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function(){
$('.delete').on('click', function() {
    //var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
    var path = 'delete';
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    var data = {};
    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrftoken;
    data ['filename'] = $('.image-input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        //contentType: false,
        //processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            alert('success');
            $('.delete').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
});
```

Comment: Could you comment on modified parts and give reasons?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('.delete').on('click', function(e) {

    e.preventDefault();
    var currentpath = window.location.pathname;
    var path = currentpath + '/delete';
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    var filename = $('.image-input').val();
    var data = JSON.stringify({ csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrftoken, filename: filename }),

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        cache: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('button.delete').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Why set `contentType` twice?

Answer (score 0):

It is also good to define the error callback  function. Why don't you debug using the inspect element of google chrome and some breakpoints?

```
$(".delete").click(function(){
    var currentpath = window.location.protocol+"//"+window.location.host;
    var path = currentpath + '/delete';
    var csrftoken = $.cookie('csrftoken');
    var data = new Object();
    data['csrfmiddlewaretoken'] = csrftoken;
    data ['filename'] = $('.image-input').val();

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(data){
            $('button.delete').css('visibility', 'hidden');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you comment on modified parts and give reasons?

Comment: i just added the comment at the top, just before the code. Before editing I posted only the piece of code.